# How would you know if the light emitted is of one wavelength or if it is a mixture of two or more wavelengths?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, light

I am just learning some chemistry after a long time without studying it and I have thought about something.

Some copper compounds emit green light when heated to flame. So, I would like to know if it is known if an emitted light is of one wavelength or if it is a mixture of two or more wavelengths.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is quite easy to measure the wavelength of light with a spectrophotometer. You might want to review how they work if you're interested.

Comment: Way back around 1666 to 1671, [Sir Isaac Newton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Newton) figured out that a prism resolved sunlight into its constituent colors. Same thing here and in the spectroscopic discovery of elements, e.g., Tl, Cs, Rb, etc.

Comment: Or try a cheap diffraction grating, e.g. https://www.amazon.com/Diffraction-Grating-Slide-Excellent-demonstrating/dp/B006ZBDRN0/ref=sr_1_38

Comment: Newton’s prisms: https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rsnr.1981.0002.

Comment: @M.Farooq I haven't downvoted but it is clear the question has flaws. For instance, what is meant by "two or more wavelengths"? Clearly "blue+yellow" versus just "green" visible wavelength(s). Your answer doesn't really dig into that point, rather touches on how you might determine the spectrum, which is not the question.

Comment: @BuckThorn, Interesting point. I don't believe these simple color mixing schemes apply in flame spectroscopy. That is why I did not invoke this point. "Green" can mean a spectrum corresponding to green wavelengths only without having blue or yellow in it or implying the *absence of green* color in the flame. Check this flame spectrum of copper, there is no yellow, but a heavy presence of red. It is tricky! https://www.sciencesource.com/archive/Flame-emission-spectrum-of-copper-SS2529806.html#/SearchResult&ITEMID=SS2529806

Comment: @M.Farooq Unfortunately your link is behind a paywall but I see what you mean: https://www.sciencephoto.com/media/1750/view

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The green light from copper flame is sadly not a single wavelength. It is very good question though because not many students even think about it. In order to "see" what wavelengths are present in a light source, you either need a spectroscope (old school way) or a monochromator with a detector (modern way). Of course you can search about Bunsen-Kirchoff spectroscope. It uses a prism to disperse the light falling on the prism.

Depending on how much interest and money you have you can easily construct a spectroscope in a shoebox (several published articles out there). Ten years ago or so I used to make CD diffraction spectroscopes in shoeboxes or cardboard boxes for seeking answers to queries like yours.

If you want spent some money ($400-500) you can buy a high quality pocket spectroscope with a wavelength scale . Then you can enjoy all light sources (except the Sun). It is fascinating to see and explore so many phenomena. You will find out by looking at the moon that it has some dark lines (never look at the Sun from a spectroscope). I am not suggesting to buy third rate products from Amazon because twice I purchased from them and the wavelengths were all wrong!

The monochromator is a fancier product. I never had the courage to buy one. They are very expensive. The most common design is a Czerny-Turner design. I am sure Prof. EdV had even fancier products which we have never fathomed :-)

This picture shows white light entering a slit, it falls on a mirror which makes all the rays parallel. The mirror sends the light to a high quality diffraction grating, the reflection diffraction grating separates wavelengths in space. The light from reflection grating falls on a focusing mirror, and the mirror focuses lies on the exit slit. The exit slit has a detector. You would slowly rotate the grating. If there are multiple wavelengths in the light source (say a flame) the detector will record a spike every time a different wavelength reaches the detector.

[image: Czerny Turner]

Comment: (+1) Glad you did an answer! Tom O'Havers' [Animated difraction grating](https://terpconnect.umd.edu/~toh/models/DiffractionGrating.html) is also useful. I used to use the Wingz version in teaching.

Comment: The awe of demonstrating that with a real open monochromator with xenon arc lamp is at another level.